# Is there a good example of lodash's _.after method

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a good practical example of how to use _.after method in lodash library?

Comment: Not sure how to answer this one. Perhaps you meant - _here's my use case, does `after()` apply_?

Answer (score 9):

Use it whenever you need to invoke a callback after it's been called *`n`* number of times.

```
var fn = _.after(3, function () {
  console.log('done');
});

fn(); // Nothing
fn(); // Nothing
fn(); // Prints "done"
```

It's useful for invoking callback when *all* async calls are complete.

```
  var done = _.after(3, function () {
      console.log('all 3 requests done!');
    });

  $.get('https://example.com', done);
  $.get('https://example.com', done);
  $.get('https://example.com', done);
```

Basic game example where player dies after getting shot 3 times.

```
 var isDead = _.after(3, function () {
      console.log('Player died!');
    });

  player1.shoot(player2, isDead); // undefined
  player1.shoot(player2, isDead); // undefined
  player1.shoot(player2, isDead); // "Player died!"
```

Basically you use `_.after` in place of a manual counter.

Comment: that would work too but not a practically useful holistic example, hence I had shamefully answer my own question.

Comment: Very good and easy to follow explanation, thanks! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: In the second example, how would you retrieve the result of each $.get function?

Answer (score -2):

There are not many examples out there but see the following for something that I use for my internal tooling.

Basically the following is a script to be run using Node. It removes documents from given Mongodb collections. That is it. But the idea is to close the DB connection only after all collections are cleaned up. We will use _.after method for that. You can read about after function [here](https://lodash.com/docs#after)

```
 var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
 MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
 Server = require('mongodb').Server;
 _ = require('lodash');

 var db = new Db('mydb', new Server('localhost', 27017));
 db.open(function(err, db) {

var collectionsToClean = ['COLLECTIONA', 'COLLECTIONB', 'COLLECTIONC'];

var closeDB = _.after(collectionsToClean.length, function() {
    db.close();
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

_.forEach(collectionsToClean, function(collectionName) {
    db.collection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {
        collection.remove({}, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Could not remove documents from ' + collectionName);
            } else {
                console.log("All documents removed from " + collectionName);
            }
            closeDB();
        });
      })
   });
});
```

You can now use this as a template for other Mongodb shell methods.

Comment: if you are answering your own question it's common courtesy to set it as community question, so you won't be suspicious in fishing for points